# При открытии новго окна родительское окно перенаправить на другой сайт

Tags: javascript

Собственно вопрос в том как проверить что родительское окно существует и перенаправить его на другой сайт.

Встречал ни раз в интернете когда заходишь например в гугл, в гугле щелкаешь по ссылке, в новом окне или вкладке открывается сайт, а страница гугла перенаправляется на какой нибудь трешовый сайт

Answer (score 1):

Может открыть сайт и запустить скрипт
[Редирект с задержкой по времени](http://www.03www.su/ex-018.html)?

Или запустить скрипт, который откроет новое окно и сделает редирект текущей? Правда я не знаю насколько хорошо так делать. и не до конца понял что именно нужно: перенаправить только что открытое или то, с которого ушли?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы — владелец сайта, и можете управлять кодом "родительского окна", то можно не усложнять и делать всё довольно логично:

```
<a target="_blank" href="ссылка для нового окна" id="xxx">текст ссылки</a>
```

Сразу при переходе по ссылке, переводим это же окно на нужный адрес:

```
document.getElementById('xxx').onclick=function(){
    window.location.href='нужная ссылка для родительского окна'
}
```

---

Если же нужно делать именно "изнутри", с дочерней страницы, то почти наверняка будут проблемы с "[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)".